# What does puppet do to fix a 'stuck' systemctl service where systemctl would refuse to start a service?

Tags: systemd, puppet, systemctl

We had a scenario where on RHEL we couldn't start an application that had been running and we had just stopped.

```
sudo systemctl start myservice
```

We didn't have access to the `journald` logs on this server, so the state of the server was a mystery.

The application instance didn't 'start' as it logs verbosely, and yet the application logs weren't touched.

My friend came along and run a puppet agent update on this box:

```
puppet agent --environment=production --test
```

After this - we could stop and start the service.

I understand that puppet has the ability to remove and create a service, and also to 'daemon-reload'. ie something like

```
systemctl stop [servicename]
systemctl disable [servicename]
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename]
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

Now I'm realising in retrospect that I should have run

```
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

I'm trying to work out what the specific thing that puppet does to get a 'stuck' service to work.

My question is: **What does puppet do to fix a 'stuck' systemctl service where systemctl would refuse to start a service?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got access to the `journald` logs and found out the following.

Interestingly enough a service will not start if the disk is full.

Puppet when running can choose to run a

```
yum clean all
```

Which fixes the issue and enables a service to start.